# Extracting text from an overflowed span tag using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, text, findall

I am very new to Python, catching up with a practice exercise. 
While doing a text extract from an HTML span tag, some portion was under "Read more" and unless I click it there, the span tag doesn't get updated with the extire text. This means while I am running BeautifulSoup and findAll for the tag and the class, the only first part, without the "read more" section, is returning as an extract. Not able to figure out how I should go after? This is a text mining exercise for hotel reviews.
Code is as below, not providing the full part:

```
url_soup=soup(url_html,"html.parser")
profiles = url_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"hotels-community-tab-common-Card__card--ihfZB hotels-community-tab-common-Card__section--4r93H"})   
for profile in profiles:
     Review_Body = profile.findAll("q",{"class":"location-review-review-list-parts-ExpandableReview__reviewText--gOmRC"})
     Review_Body = Review_Body[0].text.replace(",","").replace("\r\n","").strip(" ")
```

[Page without clicking "read more"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygN3c.jpg)
[Page after clicking "read more", when the entire text till end is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncddh.jpg)

As said, this only returns the part without clicking the "read more" and followed by a "...". PLease help. 
PS: I am not installed and using Srapy or Selenium modules. Will they be easier?

Comment: do you have the actuall link? A picture won't help...And do which library/import do you use? requests, urllib?

Comment: Yes I used requests from urllib. The link is [link]https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g304551-d304216-Reviews-or2340-The_Oberoi_New_Delhi-New_Delhi_National_Capital_Territory_of_Delhi.html [link]
All the reviews in this page has dynamic "read more" buttons. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the link you procided gives tge full data, i think you use this link: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/HollyABC

Answer (score 0):

I think that the website you are using (not the one you provided but instead: [link](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/HollyABC)
is calling different website structures, so unfortunately, i am gonna be of little help. But in case it get you going you could do this and change the code for each iteration (I would be keen to know if there is a better solution).
So again in case it helps:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as _BS

url_html = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/HollyABC"


def get_web_request(url_to_open: str):
    my_header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'}
    request = requests.get(url=url_to_open, headers=my_header)
    return request


web_page = get_web_request(url_to_open=url_html)
my_soup = _BS(web_page.text, "lxml")

container_tag = my_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'content'})
if len(container_tag) > 1:
    exit('Error with the defined container: too many answers(len shoud be one).')
print('len of container_tag', len(container_tag))

row_tags = container_tag[0].find_all('div', attrs={
    'class': 'social-section-core-CardSection__card_section--33UYa ui_card section'})
print('len of rows_tag', len(row_tags))

if row_tags is None or len(row_tags) == 0:
    exit('No result found in container')

href_url_list = []
for row_tag in row_tags:
    # find trip advisor href
    href_tag = row_tag.find_all('a', href=True)
    href = href_tag[2].get('href')
    href_url = urljoin(url_html, href)
    href_url_list.append(href_url)

print(href_url_list)

for href_url in href_url_list:
    web_page = get_web_request(url_to_open=href_url)
    my_soup = _BS(web_page.text, "lxml")
    # assuming it is always the 1st post box...
    text_tag = my_soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'firstPostBox'})
    body_tag = text_tag.find('div', attrs={'class':'postBody'}).find('p')
    print(body_tag.get_text())
```

So you should get the actual urls to each hotels, but then you would have to handle the soup for each diiferent web structure. I did it for the first one, but doesn't seem to be a great solution to be fair. Hoping it gets the ball rolling with you or the community.
Best

NB:

- I use 'lxml' which you would need to pip install, but I assume would work with 'html.parser' (not the problem here).
- I don't think Selenium will sort the problem as you will still have different web structures once you click
  -One option would be to gather href/url(like I did) but as well the partial text, and then to look for the partial text in the new last url loop. that shold work.